# distance between two Shapes/Areas in Java?

Tags: java, distance, shapes, area

If I have two `java.awt.geom.Area`'s made out of the union of various simple Shapes (Polygons and Ellipses), is there a method out there to find the distance (i.e. closest distance) between the two Areas?

To clarify: suppose I have two arbitrary Areas, each of which is created from the union of shapes of any sort:

```
//Define the first area
Area a = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 100, 100));
a.add(new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 100)));

//Define the second area
Area b = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 300, 100, 100));
b.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(250, 250, 100, 100)));
```

What I want is a method `getDistance(Area a, Area b)` that gives me a double representing the shortest distance between any point in Area a and any point in Area b. Here's an image of the above two Areas with a line in blue indicating the distance I'm interested in:

[image: Areas a and b, and the distance between them]

Is there a method out there to do this? If not, how might I implement one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a method that does that exactly; however, using `PathIterator`s, you should be able to compare point to point along the outline of the shapes and find the distance manually.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) describes how you could efficiently implement this to avoid the quadratic obvious implementation.

Comment: Thanks! The PathIterator works well for my purposes so far, especially the flattened path iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Hausdorff Distance**

Check this very clear explanation of how to use hausdorff Distance:
http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html